# Programatically create sub categories in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to create categories and sub categories programmatically in my custom module using the below code:

The below code is creating a category, but i need to create a child category.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("admin");
try
{
$_categories = Mage::getModel('recipe/category')->getCollection()->getData();  //echo "<pre>";print_r($_categories);die;
$category = Mage::getModel('recipe/category');
$category->setTitle('NEW Cate');
$category->setUrlKey('new-category');
$category->setStatus(1);
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT);
$category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
$category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('recipe/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$category->save();

$_categories = Mage::getModel('recipe/category')->getCollection()->getData();  //echo "<pre>";print_r($_categories);die;
$category = Mage::getModel('recipe/category');
$category->setTitle('Indian Cusines');
$category->setUrlKey('cusines');
$category->setStatus(1);
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT);
$category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
$category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('recipe/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$category->save();
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
   var_dump($e);
}
```

So how to create child category ??

Comment: define your variable `$parentId`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
$parentId = '2';
 try{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('your cat name');
    $category->setUrlKey('your-cat-url-key');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Categories are getting created from my above code @Kothari, i need to create child categories for the same

Answer (score 0):

In your case `parentId` **variable** is **not define**

```
$parentId=<ID of your parent category>;
```

and then **set path of your category by path of parent category**

```
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
```

Find all the categories using [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19840/45103).  Just add `$category->getId()` in 1st line after foreach

Comment: $parentId=<ID of your parent category>; how to get the Id dynamically

Comment: Also how to show the parent category title set for the child category in the grid in admin, from my above code, the column in showing blank

Comment: @SachinS what do you mean by ` how to get the Id dynamically`. You have to retrieve the id of parent category.